# How can I read an unexposed javascript variable in selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to extract the array "o" which holds data that is used to draw a polygon. Just using `driver.execute("return o")` or using console.log doesn´t work. Has someone an idea how to achieve this ?

```
const zt = function(e, t, n, r) {
            const i = r.playerId
              , {subscribe: a} = de.get(r.playerId)
              , o = r.hotspots
              , s = Ce(`#${f}skin_desktop .${f}svg_hotspots`)
              , l = 100;
            let d = null
              , c = "";
            if (!s || o.data.length <= 2)
                return;
            const {is: p, browser: u} = H.get()
              , g = p.ie || p.edge && u.version <= 18;
            o.data.splice(0, 2);
            const m = o.data.length
              , h = 1e3 / (m - 1)
              , _ = Math.max.apply(null, o.data) / l
              , v = (s.firstChild || s.content.firstChild).cloneNode(!0);
            v.getElementsByTagName("clipPath")[0].setAttribute("id", i + "_hotspotsClip"),
            v.getElementsByTagName("g")[0].setAttribute("clip-path", "url(#" + i + "_hotspotsClip)"),
            n.appendChild(v),
            d = Ce(t.polygon);
            const b = Ce(t.container)
              , y = Ce(t.progress);
            y.setAttribute("fill", o.chartColor),
            b.style.height = o.chartHeight;
            for (let f = 0; f < m; f++) {
                const e = parseInt(o.data[f], 10);
                c += h * f + "," + (l - Math.floor(e / _)) + " "
            }
            function A() {
                St(b, "visible")
            }.....
```

Comment: You can't. That's minified code, but if you have any control over it you can always add `window.testValue = o;` and read the global object property.

Comment: I believe any script you execute from the driver will have its own scope, so you'd need to execute the whole function with the inputs args...  (so convert the whole function to a string then call the fucntion with your arguments... that'll keep it all in scope)

Comment: o is set to r.hotspots so you might be able to get it from caller, esp if that's in global scope

Comment: @pguardiario I tried to use your solution in the function that calls zt but get an empty array back. How can I determine when the value is assigned so i can place the window property in the correct way?

Comment: @Ethyl you can try putting a breakpoint there in the browser debugger. It's hard to say without seeing more code

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to in certain circumstances. The problem is that `o` doesn't exist outside of that function meaning the only way you would be able to print out the contents is from *within* that function. I'm assuming you aren't on the dev team for this site so that means that you would have to find that method in the page, grab the entire `function()`, modify it, and then trigger it somehow. If it runs only on load, etc. then I don't think there's any way to get that info. If there was a way to trigger the code, e.g. a Submit button, etc., then it should output the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to modify the code and assign the value of o to a property of the window object. For example, you can add the following line after the declaration of the o variable:

```js
window.myPolygonData = o;
```

Then, in your Selenium script, you can execute javascript to retrieve the value of the window.myPolygonData property:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

# ... set up the webdriver and navigate to the page

polygon_data = driver.execute_script("return window.myPolygonData")
print(polygon_data)
```